# Need Help Rewriting Regex with only 1 Capturing Group

Tags: regex, google-bigquery

The below regex extracts what I need but I am getting this error in BigQuery:

**"Regular expression passed to REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL must not have more than 1 capturing group"**

I tried to get rid of the 2nd capturing group but can't figure out how to get the same results. Expect the results to be:

**["split.attribute1": "off","split.attribute2": "20off","split.attribute3": "excluded"]**

**Regex:**

```
(?:"split(.*?)": ")(.*?)(?:")
```

**Sample Data:**

```
{"split.attribute1": "off", "hostname": "www.test.com", "split.attribute2": "20off", "split.attribute3": "excluded"}
```

Comment: Please enter sample data and desired results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for Bigquery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(data, r'("split..*?)(?:,|})') attributes
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

if to apply to sample row in your question - output is

```
Row attributes   
1   "split.attribute1": "off"    
    "split.attribute2": "20off"  
    "split.attribute3": "excluded"
```